# Converting Drupal 7 site to static HTML

Tags: drupal

So, my team is looking at ways we could smoothly convert our archived Drupal 7 websites to static HTML. Are there any professional programs that could help with conversion, that I might have missed? So far, I've came across HTTrack and Wget. Are there any other programs I'm unaware of?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a drupal module called [Static](https://www.drupal.org/project/static) that can help you do this.

I would also suggest you read this document "[Creating a static archive of a Drupal site](https://www.drupal.org/node/27882)" if you have not already seen it.

There is also a drupal-specific forum [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/).